# Can we have this inequality $\liminf \sum_{i}\int_{[i,i+1]} f_n d\mu_{[i,i+1]}\ge \sum_{i}\liminf \int_{[i,i+1]} f_n d\mu_{[i,i+1]}?$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

For a Lebesgue measure $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_{[i,i+1]}$ on R, and $\mu_{[i,i+1]}$ is a Leb measure defined on $[0,1]$. For a sequence of measurable functions $f_n\ge 0$, we have
$$\int f_nd\mu=\sum_{i}\int f_n \chi_{[i,i+1]}d\mu=\sum_{i}\int_{[i,i+1]} f_n d\mu_{[i,i+1]}.$$ Can I get
$$\liminf \sum_{i}\int_{[i,i+1]} f_n d\mu_{[i,i+1]}\ge \sum_{i}\liminf \int_{[i,i+1]} f_n d\mu_{[i,i+1]}?$$

Comment: $\sum_n \lim \inf a_{in}\leq \lim \inf \sum_n a_{in}$ holds as long as $a_{in} \geq 0$ for all $i,n$.

Comment: Can you tell me how to prove that? Thanks!

Comment: That is a special case of Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy For another inequality $\sum_{i} \liminf \int_{i}^{i+1}f_nd\mu\ge \sum_i \int_{i}^{i+1}\liminf f_nd\mu$, is this one from Fatou's lemma?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Also, is the Fatou's lemma about interchanging limit and integral. But in yours, it is about interchanging the sum and limit. Are they same?

Comment: An infite sums is an integral with respect to counting measure on $\mathbb N$.